# Why the objects i created with particle system failed to be edited in shading?

Tags: shaders

I don't know why shading only occured on the plane not on the grass that i created.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You either set the particle's material in the *Render* pane of the particle settings, or if you're instancing an object it'll instance with its own material, whatever it is set to.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I instanced an object. So do i need to shade the object that I'm instancing first?

Comment: Yes.  If you want randomness in the instancer you might be looking at Geometry -> Random per Island

Comment: cool thank you for the solution, worked out pretty well!

Comment: @Shuying Zhang if Allen has answered correctly, please check the validation button